# ImportXML for live exchange rates from Xe.com

Tags: xml, xpath, import

I'm trying to import specific currency exchange rates,i.e. JPY-USD, JPY-EUR,JPY-INR etc from XE.com into Google spreadsheets using Import XML.
How can I figure out the x path that I need from XE.com's page source? Help would be greatly appreciated!

URL: http://www.xe.com/currency/jpy-japanese-yen?r=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IMPORTHTML` instead :

```
=IMPORTHTML ("http://www.xe.com/currency/xau-gold-ounce","table",1)
```

xe.com returns a table with the data which you could then use a HLOOKUP to only return the data for USD. Eg. :

```
=hlookup("USD",{IMPORThtML("http://www.xe.com/currency/xau-gold-ounce","table",1)},2,false)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Is there a way I can autoupdate this data?

Comment: @SGK, Use Ajax to autoUpdate <div> using `setInterval`.

Comment: @SGK Also Keep habbit of accepting and upvoting the answers if you find them useful. Thanks.